# Create a hole inside of a Polygon - Google Maps Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

So I've been working on an app that uses zones represented as Polygons. What I want to do is have the map dark everywhere except where these polygons are.

The orange line is where I want it to be dark and the area inside it is what I want to stay the same.

I should also say that it gets the polygons off of a KML file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0UdH.jpg

Thanks

Comment: "Create a whole inside of a Polygon"  You mean, creating a 'hole'?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Has been corrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using a `UIBeizerPath` to draw polygon from KML file, you can create a masked view as

```
    let mask = CAShapeLayer(layer: layer)
    mask.path = polygon.cgPath //polygon is your UIBeizerPath
    mask.lineWidth = 5.0
    mask.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    mask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.mapView.mask = mask
```